# velero backup failing for AWS EKS Cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to take k8s cluster namespace backup using velero. i have successfully installed velero pod is up and running.

```
[root@master velero]# kubectl get all -n velero
NAME                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/velero-568f5554fc-h9k8x   1/1     Running   0          21m

NAME             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/velero   ClusterIP   172.20.248.205   <none>        8085/TCP   21m

NAME                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/velero   1/1     1            1           21m

NAME                                DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/velero-568f5554fc   1         1         1       21m
```

Its seems all good as per the kubernetes get command.

Here the velero back describe

```
[root@master velero]# velero backup describe nginx-backup-sep-29
Name:         nginx-backup-sep-29
Namespace:    velero
Labels:       velero.io/storage-location=default
Annotations:  velero.io/source-cluster-k8s-gitversion=v1.20.7-eks-d88609
              velero.io/source-cluster-k8s-major-version=1
              velero.io/source-cluster-k8s-minor-version=20+

Phase:  Failed (run `velero backup logs nginx-backup-sep-29` for more information)

Namespaces:
  Included:  nginx-namespace
  Excluded:  <none>

Resources:
  Included:        *
  Excluded:        <none>
  Cluster-scoped:  auto

Label selector:  <none>

Storage Location:  default

Snapshot PVs:  auto

TTL:  720h0m0s

Hooks:  <none>

Backup Format Version:  1

Started:    2021-09-29 06:41:42 +0000 UTC
Completed:  <n/a>

Expiration:  2021-10-29 06:41:42 +0000 UTC

Persistent Volumes: <none included>
```

velero get backups

```
velero backup get
NAME                  STATUS   CREATED                         EXPIRES   STORAGE LOCATION   SELECTOR
nginx-backup-sep-29   Failed   2021-09-29 06:41:42 +0000 UTC   29d       default            <none>
```

finally when i see velero deployment logs

```
kubectl logs deployment/velero -n velero
unable to locate ObjectStore plugin named velero.io/aws" logSource="pkg/controller/download_request_controller.go:148"
time="2021-09-29T06:45:29Z" level=error msg="Error getting backup store for this location" backupLocation=default controller=backup-sync error="unable to locate ObjectStore plugin named velero.io/aws" logSource="pkg/controller/backup_sync_controller.go:175"
time="2021-09-29T06:45:59Z" level=error msg="Error getting backup store for this location" backupLocation=default controller=backup-sync error="unable to locate ObjectStore plugin named velero.io/aws" logSource="pkg/controller/backup_sync_controller.go:175"
time="2021-09-29T06:46:29Z" level=error msg="Error getting backup store for this location" backupLocation=default controller=backup-sync error="unable to locate ObjectStore plugin named velero.io/aws" logSource="pkg/controller/backup_sync_controller.go:175"
time="2021-09-29T06:46:59Z" level=error msg="Error getting backup store for this location" backupLocation=default controller=backup-sync error="unable to locate ObjectStore plugin named velero.io/aws" logSource="pkg/controller/backup_sync_controller.go:175"
time="2021-09-29T06:47:29Z" level=error msg="Error getting backup store for this location" backupLocation=default controller=backup-sync error="unable to locate ObjectStore plugin named velero.io/aws" logSource="pkg/controller/backup_sync_controller.go:175"
```

cloud you please some one help me on this